# how can i fix the following json error Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Tags: json

{
"draw": 1,
"recordsTotal": 1,
"recordsFiltered": 1,
"data": [
["dfcgvbh",
"2020-10-28 06:10:00",
"5 Minute",
"5 Question",
"1 Mark",
"-1 Mark",
"Pending</span>",
"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t

Comment: You're not showing enough; just a piece of badly formed json, no code... Check json [here](https://jsonlint.com/) for validity.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is invalid, most likely unfinished. You should at least add `"]]}` in the end so it would look like this:

`{ "draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 1, "recordsFiltered": 1, "data": [ ["dfcgvbh", "2020-10-28 06:10:00", "5 Minute", "5 Question", "1 Mark", "-1 Mark", "Pending</span>", "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t"]]}`

Validate JSON strings here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not legal JSON. It looks like it is truncated. You need to make sure to use the whole input.

```json
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "data": [
        [
            "dfcgvbh",
            "2020-10-28 06:10:00",
            "5 Minute",
            "5 Question",
            "1 Mark",
            "-1 Mark",
            "Pending</span>",
            "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
```

- The string started on line 14 is not closed
- The array started on line 6 is not closed
- The array started on line 5 is not closed
- The object started on line 1 is not closed

It looks like there is simply a piece missing.